# Under which user are PHP scripts running?

Tags: php, wordpress, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

Running Wordpress 5.02 on Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS 8.

Under which windows user account are PHP scripts running? Or how can I find this out? I need to give write permissions to directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute this custom `PHP Script`. Supports `(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)`

```
<?php
echo 'Current script owner: ' . get_current_user();
?>
```

Comment: Yes that's it! It returned IUSR as script owner.